# CUDA array duplicity check and repair

Tags: arrays, cuda

I want create random int array in CUDA. And I need to check for duplicity on array index 0-9, 10-19 ... and repair them.

Any idea, how to make it effective? I really dont want check each element with each other.

Here is my code:

```
__global__ void generateP(int *d_p, unsigned long seed)
{
    int i = X * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x * X;

    int buffer[X];

    curandState state;
    curand_init(seed, i, 0, &state);

    for (int j = 0; j < X; j++)
    {
        float random = HB + (curand_uniform(&state) * (LB - HB));
        buffer[j] = (int)truncf(random);
    }

    // TODO unique check and repair duplicity

    for (int k = 0; k < X; k++)
    {
        d_p[i] = buffer[k];
        i++;
    }   
}
```

Is there in CUDA some kind of Contains function? Thanks for help.

Comment: Seriously, google for Fisher-Yates shuffle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really are asking the wrong question here. You should be looking for a way of randomly ordering a list of unique values, rather than attempting to fill a list with unique random numbers by searching and replacing duplicates repeatedly until you have the unique list. The latter is terribly inefficient and a poor fit to a data parallel execution model like CUDA.

There are simple, robust algorithms for randomly shuffling list of values that only require at most N calls to a random generator in order to shuffle a list of N values. The [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) is almost universally used for this.

I'm not going to comment much on this code except to say that it illustrates one approach to doing this, using one thread per list. It isn't intended to be performant, just a teaching example to get you started. I think it probably does close to what you are asking for (more based on your previous attempt at this question than this one). I recommend you study it as a lead-in to writing your own implementation which does whatever it is you are trying to do.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <curand_kernel.h>

struct source
{
    int baseval;
    __device__ source(int _b) : baseval(_b) {};
    __device__ int operator()(int v) { return baseval + v; };
};

__device__ int urandint(int minval, int maxval, curandState_t& state)
{
    float rval = curand_uniform(&state);
    rval *= (float(maxval) - float(minval) + 0.99999999f);
    rval += float(minval);
    return (int)truncf(rval);
}

template<int X>
__global__ void kernel(int* out, int N, unsigned long long seed)
{
    int tidx = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    if (tidx < N) {
        curandState_t state;
        curand_init(seed, tidx, 0, &state);

        int seq[X];
        source vals(tidx * X);
        // Fisher Yeats Shuffle straight from Wikipedia
#pragma unroll
        for(int i=0; i<X; ++i) {
            int j = urandint(0, i, state);
            if (j != i)
                seq[i] = seq[j];
            seq[j] = vals(i);
        }

        // Copy local shuffled sequence to output array
        int* dest = &out[X * tidx];
        memcpy(dest, &seq[0], X * sizeof(int));
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    const int X = 10;
    const int nsets = 200;

    int* d_result;
    size_t sz = size_t(nsets) * sizeof(int) * size_t(X);
    cudaMalloc((void **)&d_result, sz);
    int tpb = 32;
    int nblocks = (nsets/tpb) + ((nsets%tpb !=0) ? 1 : 0);
    kernel<X><<<nblocks, tpb>>>(d_result, nsets, std::time(0));

    int h_result[nsets][X];
    cudaMemcpy(&h_result[0][0], d_result, sz, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    for(int i=0; i<nsets; ++i) {
        std::cout << i << " : ";
        for(int j=0; j<X; ++j) {
            std::cout << h_result[i][j] << ",";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    cudaDeviceReset();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for simle example, how to use Fisher Yeates shuffle. This is where I can start solve my problem. I really tried solve this wrong way.